# Regex for exactly number of chars in random order

Tags: regex

I have a regex that accepts 8-10 chars: only # and - (in random order)

> ^[-#]{8,10}$

But I need exactly 8 of # and 0-2 of -

For example, proper strings are:

```
-########-
########
##-###-###
```

Regex

> ^[#]{8}[-][0,2]$

It doesn't work cause accepts only 8 of# and some of - in this particular order

Comment: `^(?=[#-]{8,10}$)#*(?:-#*){0,2}#*$` https://regex101.com/r/VqBCnW/1 or `^(?!(?:#*-){3})[#-]{8,10}$` https://regex101.com/r/66tE7U/1

Comment: Yes, but [`^(?=.{8,10}$)#*(?:-#*){0,2}#*$`](https://regex101.com/r/nhCtOt/1) is fine, too.

Comment: Wiktor and the fourth bird, thanks, but your solution accepts 10 of #. And the condition in task was - exactly 8 of #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert 8-10 chars, and match 8 # chars surrounded by optional `-` chars

```
^(?=.{8,10}$)(?:-*#){8}-*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{8,10}$)` Positive lookahead to assert 8 - 10 characters in total
- `(?:-*#){8}` Match 8 times optional `-` and then `#`
- `-*` Match optional trailing `-`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2MGe1U/1).